# Rails - On new object form, how to display a list of associated objects ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When creating a new illustration object, I wish to display a selectable list of existing novel_ids (primary key). That is to say, the illustration must be added to an existing novel.  I'm unable to find the proper syntax to do so.  The associations are tested and work appropriately.  In the future I'd like to choose from a list of novel titles but have the novel_id assigned to the illustrations behind the scenes.  Thank you.

This is what I have so far, I've tried many different styles of this statement with no luck:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :novel_id%><br />
  <%= f.collection_select(:novel_id, Novel.all, :id, :prompt => true) %>
</div>
```

Comment: A round bracket is missing. use this, ` <%= f.select(:novel_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Novel.all, 'id', 'name')) %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this...

```
 <%= f.select(:novel_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Novel.all, 'id', 'name')) %>
```

Comment: Your solution has gotten rid of my original error, however now I'm getting the following errors: `/home/joe/Documents/workspace/archive/app/views/illustrations/_form.html.erb:49: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
'); end 
       ^
/home/joe/Documents/workspace/archive/app/views/illustrations/_form.html.erb:51: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')'
/home/joe/Documents/workspace/archive/app/views/illustrations/_form.html.erb:53: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'`

Comment: sorry, a round bracket was missing. check my answer now.

Comment: I have implemented this solution and it works as desired.  I'd like to go a step further if you can help.  Several of the books I'll have listed have multiple editions.  The data model has these as separate instances of the Novel class.  Is there a way to display both the novel name and edition to select from, and have the new illustration be associated with the proper novel-edition combination?